# Formatting Excel rows between values programmatically with C#

Tags: c#, excel, formatting

I'm working in a proyect and I have to generate an Excel with formatting conditions. I was able to do it with equals values (Ex: B2 = "Correct Value") but in some cases I have to check if the value is between two values (Ex: " 2 < B2 < 4 ") I have this code:

```cs
FormatCondition[] format = new FormatCondition[datos.Length];
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range[] cells = new Range[datos.Length];
            for (int i = 1; i < datos.Length; i++)
            {
                string condition = "";
                if (qTipo[i - 1] == "Num" && qMax[i - 1] != "" && qMin[i - 1] != "")
                { // DOES NOT WORK
                    condition = $"=Y(B{i + 1}<{qMax[i - 1]};B{i + 1}>{qMin[i - 1]})"; // THIS RETURNS "=Y(B4<6;B4>4)"
                    format[i] = (FormatCondition)(xlWorksheet.get_Range($"B{i + 1}",
                    Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Type.Missing,
                    condition));
                }
                else
                {   //WORKS
                    condition = $"=B{i + 1}=\"{qCorrecto[i - 1]}\""; // THIS RETURNS "=B2="Correct Value""
                    format[i] = (FormatCondition)(xlWorksheet.get_Range($"B{i + 1}",
                    Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Type.Missing,
                    condition));
                }
                format[i].Interior.Color = 0x0000FF00;
                datos[i] = new String[2];
                datos[i][0] = qPregunta[i - 1];
                datos[i][1] = "";
            }
```

When I execute this code it gives me "Invalid argument exception" on the Add statement.

Merci,
Miguel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to my super inteligence I was able to resolve this problem. The code I needed was:

```
format[i] = (FormatCondition)(xlWorksheet.get_Range($"B{i + 1}", Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlC‌​ellValue, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, $"={qMax[i - 1]}", $"={qMin[i - 1]}"));
```